# database or ObjectOutputStream, Object specific member or actual object for reference

Tags: java, database, object, reference, objectoutputstream

I'm working on an application for a pharmacy , basically this application has a class "item" and another class "selling invoices" which logs selling processes .
So my question here if the pharmacy is expected to have about ten thousand products in stock, and I'm storing these products in a linked list of type Item, and storing the invoices in linked list also , then on closing the app i save them using object output stream and reload them upon the start, Is it a bad practice ? Have I to use database instead? 
My second question is, if i continue on using linkedlist and object output stream , what is better for performance and memory, storing the actual item as a field member in the invoice class or just its ID and then getting the item upon recalling using this ID reference, so what's better ?
Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0):

It is a bad idea to use ObjectOutputStream like that.

Here are some of the reasons:

1. If your application crashes (or the power fails) before you "save", then all changes are lost.
2. Saving "all objects" is expensive.
3. Serialized objects are opaque.  It is only practical to look at them from Java code.
4. Serialized objects are fragile.  If your application classes change, you may find that old serialized objects can no longer be read.  That's bad enough, but now consider what happens if your client wants to look at pharmacy records from 5 years ago ... from a backup tape.
5. Serialized objects provide no way of searching ... apart from reading all of the objects one at a time.
6. Designs which involve reading all objects into memory do not scale.  You are liable to run out of memory.  Or compromise on your requirements to avoid running out of memory.

By contrast:

1. A database won't lose any changes have been committed.  They are much more resilient to things like application errors and system level failures.
2. Committing database changes is not as expensive, because you only write data that has changed.
3. Typical databases can be viewed, queried, and if necessary repaired using an off-the-shelf database tool.
4. Changing Java code doesn't break the database.  And for some schema changes, there are ways to migrate the database schema and records to match an updated database.
5. Databases have indexes and query languages for implementing efficient search.
6. Databases scale because the primary copy of the data is on disk, not in memory.